# Are people voting less these days?

Tags: discussion, support, voting, statistics

I feel like decent questions are receiving fewer upvotes these days (but interestingly, bad questions are receiving many downvotes and close votes). I'm not saying this is a bad thing for the site, I'm just interested to see whether there is any data to support the position.

Has anyone made a graph of votes-per-view plotted against date?  If not, where should I start looking in order to make one myself?

---

To clarify, I was interested in the number of votes per view on a question. For example, maybe there were 20 votes cast for 100 views a couple of years ago, and now it might be down to 10. I was not intending to ask about the number of upvotes relative to downvotes, which is more a measure of post quality than voting participation.

Comment: [Sure](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/219032/number-of-votes-per-month#graph).

Comment: perfect. cheers

Comment: Note that the graph doesn't necessarily support your position. It could be the result of an declining ratio of decent to bad questions.

Comment: I have to agree with Ross' point here. Note the recent, symmetrical increase of downvotes in Hans's graph.

Comment: Every question / answer I use in my command I upvote the answer and the question to thank the answer person and the person who asked the question. Simple reason, they did a service for me. Because now I don't need to look for 4 more hours. Just a big thanks to everyone here!

Comment: @HansPassant This graph is interesting too but I looked closer at the queries and unless I'm mistaken it does not really answer my question - I want to show _votes-per-view_ on the y axis.  The absolute number of votes is not a normalised measure so it only has meaning when seen in relation to the number of downvotes.  This can be a measure of question quality as mentioned.  I was more interested in the number of votes per view.

Comment: I think perhaps πάντα ῥεῖ has changed the meaning of my question by modifying the title, I will roll it back and edit with a clarification

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'm not sure if the increase in downvotes is a real effect, or just an artifact of the graph. Downvoted questions get deleted, but not instantly. About 44% of my own downvotes are on deleted posts and the ratio is probably even bigger for people who downvote more questions and less answers. If the graph doesn't include downvotes on deleted posts, that would explain the spike.

Comment: "votes per view on a question" would be a fragile measure. 100,000 views from Reddit from those without rep to vote or even unregistered can drag it down beyond any meaningful value. What you need is more likely votes per user per day, probably separate to users who can only vote up and those who can vote both up and down

Comment: I'd be interested to see the number of up/down votes on only questions that haven't had any close votes, and also have that graph normalised to take site popularity into account (perhaps votes per question?)

Comment: Or perhaps only looking at questions with a positive overall score, do older questions receive more upvotes than they do now?

Comment: You have a "feeling" about something, but it will be impossible to answer know your "feeling" is right, because it relies on something that is not well defined: the "decent question".

Comment: @juanchopanza notion of "decent" (_well-received_) question seems to be defined since [asking day badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234259/165773) were introduced

Comment: @gnat But that relies on vote count, so it wouldn't help to answer this question.

Comment: @juanchopanza I think you are misunderstanding what I've intended.  I'm not interested in a measure of the "decent question", but in a measure of user participation.  i.e. are users engaging in the voting process, or just lurking and reading.  This should be much easier to quantify.

Comment: @wim "I feel like decent questions are receiving less upvotes these days... I'm just interested to see whether there is any data to support the position. " Difficult to get data to support something so ill-defined. Of course, this is meta, and people my give opinions on have the same feeling or not, or whether their voting patterns have changed. Personally, I would say I come across very few "decent" questions these days.

Comment: OK, I should have written "questions are receiving less votes" .. (and as a corollary, decent questions receiving fewer upvotes)

Comment: @wim Also, there is a daily voting limit, and more traffic on the site. So it is possible to burn all ones votes on down-voting bad questions.

Comment: I have made sure to vote everyday, but I'm sure 1 user cannot make a difference :P.

Comment: I would like to see a similar graph for answers. I think people are voting less for answers too.

Comment: Upvotes on *questions?* Seems counterproductive.

Comment: I'm pretty sure people are voting less in the tags I frequent. The hot answers in the [SQL Server tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/hot?filter=month) currently has the hottest answer at only +10 for the entire month. This is much lower than I remember being typical say 18 months or 2 years ago.

Comment: This is what I would expect. It's not that all the good questions have been asked already, but most of the good *fairly obvious* questions have been asked. Time was when you could get 209 votes and 32 favourites for asking something as basic as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816673/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-java-on-windows); do that these days and you (rightly) get a slap and a closed-duplicate.

Comment: related discussion at MSE: [Why are votes per post on the decrease (what can we do to improve this)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80312/165773) (with [this fantastic answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216297/165773) _"I don't know what happened, but that trend has been reversed..."_)

Comment: Well, I log in once in a while, glance at the front page, usually see nothing interesting, and leave. No votes there.

Comment: I vote up almost all highly scored answers just by default

Answer (score 51):

To give a simple interpretation on [Hans Passant's graph](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/219032/number-of-votes-per-month#graph) for votes per month:

[image: The chart has lines for the total, just up votes, and just down votes from 2009 to 2018. The number of down votes starts going up in 2011 and has been around 50000 since early 2015. The total number of up votes has been around 100000 for 2017 - 2018, down from its all time high of 150000 in 2015.]

It looks for me as the site gains popularity, the number of low quality questions increased, and so did downvotes in relation to upvotes.

So yes, upvotes are less relative to downvotes recently, since the quality questions posted are less than the low quality questions (just look at the last data points and their relative distance of votes).

Comment: Take into account the roomba hasn't deleted the most recent bad questions yet and the downvotes on those skew the results.

Comment: upvotes really haven't decreased much at all.. there are just a lot more downvotes.

Comment: @lostsock _"... there are just a lot more downvotes"_ Because of a lot more VLQ questions as I suspect.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It might not be just that popularity has increased. Perhaps it is simply that all the good questions that can be asked have already been asked.

Comment: Interesting enough. But not that much if not compared to population, preferably active pop. Spread on new vs. old questions would also be interesting.

Comment: Yeah, but that diagram is only a part of the picture. How does the vote count per [active] member looks like? How does it look per question/answer? Or per new questions/answers?

Comment: Here's a [version of the graph that shows all up/down votes, not just ones within 31 days of the question being asked](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/222039/number-of-votes-per-month#graph). There is a minor downturn in Feb-June, but nothing major. It seems pretty normal to me.

Comment: Here's a version of @Rachel's graph that shows the [relative proportion of upvotes vs downvotes as a fraction of total votes cast](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/222068/291447/number-of-votes-per-month). The gap has definitely narrowed recently, but there are still four(ish) upvotes cast for every downvote.

Comment: @sashoalm Of course, all the good questions that can be asked have already been asked. Also [everything that can be invented has been invented](http://www.quotationspage.com/weblog/2005-08-26-239/). ;-)

Comment: @Palec Isn't finding these an [NP problem space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity))? ;-) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Impossible to formalize, IMO. But if you tried to imply that [you know good question when you see it](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), I must say I do too. :-)

Comment: @Palec Let's leave this to the AI experts :-P ...

Comment: @Palec Yes, by "all" I meant most. It's akin to market saturation, like you could make a lot of money on Android Apps in the beginning, but now - not so much.

Comment: *"upvotes are less relative to downvotes recently,"*  Not just relative. They also have decreased in absolute numbers per month.

Comment: @sashoalm Put this way, I can agree. Most common Qs are covered, now it’s time for a) questions about new or more exotic technologies or features thereof, and b) maintenance of the knowledge base we made so far.

Comment: Hmmm...correlation doesn't imply causation. While I'd be willing to bet your right, the shift to more down-votes could easily be explained as much as a change in the community rather than a change in the quality of posts.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams _" the shift to more down-votes could easily be explained as much as a change in the community rather than a change in the quality of posts"_ Agreed, that's why I meant to _"Give a simple interpretation"_. We can't tell the reasons certainly by looking at this graph, it's just a matter of probability.

Comment: @Lundin looking at the SEDE [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/219032/number-of-votes-per-month#graph) the votes depict the number of votes per month. And the live query shows till 2018. In the answer you only see  a screenshot from when the answer was posted ...

Answer (score 6):

> To clarify, I was interested in the number of votes per view on a question. E.g. maybe there were 20 votes cast for 100 views a couple of years ago, and now it might be down to 10.

This is not something we know.

The SE Dev Team probably won't even know this unless they tracked individual view statistics, and I don't think they do since tracking each individual view would take up a ridiculous amount of space. Also, I know the same user can count for multiple views, and if SE was tracking View stats I doubt that would be allowed.

Best case scenario is to find an old data dump, and run a query like [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/222156/views-per-vote#graph) against both the old data and compare it with the same query run against the newer data.

A graph of the current data would look like this :

[image]

To clarify the data

- X Axis is date at which questions were Asked
- Y Axis is the total # of Up and Down votes that question received as of today, divided by the number of Views as of today
- The ratio has been multiplied by a huge number to make it visible on the graph

Obviously, questions that have been around much longer have accumulated many more views than newer questions (including repeat-viewers, who can only vote once but [can count for multiple views](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270479/302677)), so they naturally have a much lower VotePerView ratio.

Also, keep in mind deleted questions don't count in this graph, and there is a roomba that auto-deletes any low-scoring questions, which is most likely why the right side of the graph looks so high. For example, [this version of the graph](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/222159/views-per-vote#graph) only counts upvotes, and the top of it is roughly 0.013, compared to 0.023 in current graph.)

Comment: "I know the same user can count for multiple views" [citation needed]

Comment: @Braiam I don't recall the exact Meta.SE post, however [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270479/302677) looks close enough. I'll add the link to my answer too :)

Comment: I wonder if something like this is relevant too, it shows that the number of votes per question has remained fairly consistent (for answers with a positive overall score) http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/222089/average-up-votes-per-post#graph

Comment: actually, SO does keep a tracking of how many views a question has and is displayed right next to the amount of votes and answers in the question list.  One viewer is counted one time.

Comment: @Greg Total number of Views is tracked, however individual views are not. For example, I've noticed if you view a question on two separate days, it counts as two separate views for the TotalViews counter. I've seen meta discussions about this in the past, and you can find a lot more info on how it works with a meta.SE search, such as the link I added in my earlier comment

Comment: my mistake,  I guess I should have had a few more cups of coffee this morning

Answer (score -6):

The other answer answers your question, but I will answer to the other part:

> To clarify, I was interested in the number of votes per view on a
> question. E.g. maybe there were 20 votes cast for 100 views a couple
> of years ago, and now it might be down to 10. I was not intending to
> ask about the number of upvotes relative to downvotes, which is more a
> measure of post quality than voting participation.

You are totally wrong here ([link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/222063/views-per-vote#graph)):
[image]
Users here from 3 years ago started to respond faster to bad or good quality questions. When I tried to do both to answers and question it was down to vote per 5 views, while views can be even from guests.

NOTE: maybe need fix, I never programmed in SQL, well except this time.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, the link you posted to Data.SE does not incorporate Views in any way, and the graph it displays does not match the graph in your answer. In addition, accurate data like that is very hard to obtain since there is no timestamp on any of the views, so naturally older questions will have many more views than newer questions. (Also in the linked Data.SE query, you are only including Votes cast within 31 days of question creation. Was that intentional?)

Comment: @Rachel Fixed. When someone view something they able to vote those posts too. (The top questions are still upvoted while being old) By the way if you use problems that are similar to `Also in the linked Data.SE query, you are only including ...` in the fixed query, it would be good if you could fix it.

Comment: Views per Vote is exactly the measure that the original poster asked for. But somehow I cannot believe this graph - it goes to zero???

Comment: Not down to zero, but a huge drop in the views per vote ratio.

Comment: @KugBuBu I'm sorry, but that query and graph is horribly inaccurate :) You can't identify ViewsPerMonth because that data isn't tracked, and you're using counting Accepted+Upvotes, not Upvotes+Downvotes. To get a more accurate query, you'd need something like [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/222154/views-per-vote#graph), however even that isn't very accurate because there is no way of knowing the ViewsPerVote from X years ago compared to now. We can only see it as of *right now*, and naturally older posts have a much lower ViewsToVote ratio than newer ones.

Comment: @Trilarion Down to 19, I added link to the data.

Comment: @Rachel I think I got your point, if you think that users stop voting questions that are a bit old, then make query and do votes per posts. I am not feeling like writing code in this language ever again. ם.ם really horrible language.

Comment: @KugBuBu :) SQL really isn't that bad once you get to know it, and I am glad you made the effort. I wouldn't have bothered to [post my own answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270479/302677) otherwise. Queries to find answers to questions like these aren't very easy.

Comment: @Rachel I dislike wordy-languages (well, except some human-languages). Thanks I've done it by copy-paste from Hans Passant's query, and `while(error()) try();` to death.