# Why doesn't anyone vote anymore?

Tags: discussion, voting

It seems that way to me. You find some questions from years ago with hundreds of votes, but seems like a good question now will get less than 10. I'm a newcomer, so I'm in no position to speculate. Maybe it just takes a long time to build up votes/views.

Something else I've noticed, is that some of the older questions can be one liners and they still have many votes. Seems that if you ask a question like that now, it will get downvoted right away.

Maybe my real question is, in your opinion has the culture of SO changed over the years?

Comment: Stack Overflow gets [7500](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) questions per day (and at least that many answers per day too).  It becomes quite difficult to vote on all of them each day and unless you've got eyeballs writing a good and interesting question, it can be difficult to get any votes on it.

Comment: *Maybe my real question is, in your opinion has the culture of SO changed over the years?* Yes. Everything evolves.

Comment: You keep mentioning the years... If something's been around for years longer the chances are it will get more votes...

Comment: @MichaelT That is true, maybe it's just purely because of volume. But we see and answer plenty of questions every day, we definitely have no shortage of votes to use.

Comment: @EternalHour I frequently run out of votes on Stack Overflow.  Some days I even do it twice ([90% of everything is crap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon's_law) and spending 36 out of 40 votes/day on crap which gets deleted that day gives you another 36 votes to cast). And most people don't try to vote on everything they see... they only vote on what they looked for *that day*.  And there's voting fatigue too (see how many days in a row you can cast 40 votes).

Comment: @MichaelT I believe what you've said is worthy of an answer :)

Comment: SO has a serious [Help Vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) problem. You get weary to vote for or answer questions that googling for their title would answer

Comment: Yeah.  I'm tired of all the bone-idle deadbeats who just want SO contributors to work for them for free.  So much life-force has been leached away by the bad questions that I no longer have the strength to move the mouse to the upvote arrow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are people voting less these days?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270387/are-people-voting-less-these-days)

Comment: The "real" question is waaaaaaay too broad. Instead of asking for the 6 year history of voting culture, perhaps just start by reading the thousands of meta posts related to it. Further, you answer your own original question, "it just takes a long time to build up votes/views". This is true for most posts, some are instant classics but those are few and far between.

Comment: @TravisJ I understand it's a broad question, but it was meant to open a dialogue with many possible answers which is why I tagged it "discussion".  
Apparently others have been curious about this as well since there are similar questions. But, I did search for this question before I asked it and didn't find anything.
Which points to another possible reason why it may appear there is a lower concentration of votes. Similar questions which aren't ranked highly in an index so they're not found by searching.

Comment: I had really good question, and less than 24 hours I got there 25 votes, a bit later more and it stopped at about 50. (My case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718990) People vote, but probably more consious about it. (Like judging more, but if the post is good then they upvote)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming I didn't get [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/244846/votes-and-posts-per-year) wrong, there is no evidence of a slowdown in voting on Stack Overflow in the past three years. There's been a dip, but it has picked up.

[image]

Now, questions posted in 2008 have had several years to garner votes, and were much less likely to be duplicates. Answers to those have had exposure in search engine results for as much time. So they've had many more opportunities to garner votes (up or down).

In contrast, you've only been registered for four month, so none of your post has had nearly as much exposure.

Some "interesting" questions and answers do get tons of votes on their first few days of existence, thanks mainly to various forms of promotion (reddit, Twitter, hot questions sidebar, etc.), but those are exceptions.

---

[Another take](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/247515/votes-per-post-aging) on this voting business:

```
+----------+----------+------------------+---------------+--------------+
| PostDate | VoteDate | AccumulatedVotes | PostsThatYear | VotesPerPost |
+----------+----------+------------------+---------------+--------------+
|     2008 |     2008 |           583491 |        286752 | 2.03         |
|     2008 |     2009 |           874866 |        286752 | 3.05         |
|     2008 |     2010 |          1148075 |        286752 | 4            |
|     2008 |     2011 |          1527870 |        286752 | 5.33         |
|     2008 |     2012 |          2019099 |        286752 | 7.04         |
|     2008 |     2013 |          2572543 |        286752 | 8.97         |
|     2008 |     2014 |          3014878 |        286752 | 10.51        |
+----------+----------+------------------+---------------+--------------+
|     2009 |     2009 |          2205618 |       1317629 | 1.67         |
|     2009 |     2010 |          2759614 |       1317629 | 2.09         |
|     2009 |     2011 |          3556222 |       1317629 | 2.7          |
|     2009 |     2012 |          4660626 |       1317629 | 3.54         |
|     2009 |     2013 |          5904205 |       1317629 | 4.48         |
|     2009 |     2014 |          6892856 |       1317629 | 5.23         |
+----------+----------+------------------+---------------+--------------+
|     2010 |     2010 |          3087782 |       2202789 | 1.4          |
|     2010 |     2011 |          3991132 |       2202789 | 1.81         |
|     2010 |     2012 |          5226031 |       2202789 | 2.37         |
|     2010 |     2013 |          6691896 |       2202789 | 3.04         |
|     2010 |     2014 |          7863220 |       2202789 | 3.57         |
+----------+----------+------------------+---------------+--------------+
|     2011 |     2011 |          4501064 |       3533172 | 1.27         |
|     2011 |     2012 |          6164340 |       3533172 | 1.74         |
|     2011 |     2013 |          8117237 |       3533172 | 2.3          |
|     2011 |     2014 |          9649645 |       3533172 | 2.73         |
+----------+----------+------------------+---------------+--------------+
|     2012 |     2012 |          5630952 |       4553915 | 1.24         |
|     2012 |     2013 |          7766357 |       4553915 | 1.71         |
|     2012 |     2014 |          9472805 |       4553915 | 2.08         |
+----------+----------+------------------+---------------+--------------+
|     2013 |     2013 |          6143935 |       5510342 | 1.11         |
|     2013 |     2014 |          8147464 |       5510342 | 1.48         |
+----------+----------+------------------+---------------+--------------+
|     2014 |     2014 |          4729210 |       5138896 | 0.92         |
+----------+----------+------------------+---------------+--------------+
```

What this tells you is that, for example, there are 287k non-deleted posts in 2008. At year end 2008, 583k votes (up or down only, not accept) had been cast, averging 2.03 votes per post.

Zoom forward to 2011, 3.5M posts were created that year, and got 4.5M votes that year, so 1.27 votes per post (first line of the 2011 "block"). Meanwhile, folks continued voting on older stuff. By the end of 2011, the posts from 2008 had accumulated 1.5M votes total, for an average votes/post of 5.3.

For this year, 5.1M posts so far, 4.7M votes so far, so .92 votes per post average. Meanwhile posts from 2011 have matured to 2.7, and those from 2008 are out of control with a whopping 10.5 votes per post.

From this view of the data, you can see that people haven't stopped voting, but they're  voting a lot on older posts (65% of the votes cast this year were for posts created before 2014). Posts created this year (about 23% of total posts) received 35% of the votes.

---

I'll summarize this as:

- Voting activity compared to posting (Q&A) activity dipped from 2008 to 2011 but has risen back.
- You get less votes on new posts (on average) than you used to back in 2008. (Votes are spread, unevenly, on the whole database.)
- (Optimistic) People are finding more and more answers to their questions in the database we've built, and are voting on them when they find them useful
- (Pessimistic) The rate at which new posts are entering the system is possibly too high for the community to properly evaluate them (in terms of "rise to the top" triage; less than one vote per "fresh" post doesn't make for much differentiation).

Comment: Very impressive data Mat, thanks! I'm not basing the observation just on my questions, but others I come across.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216297/165773

Comment: Nice numbers, that was interesting :)

Comment: There's a mistake in your query that makes it look too good.  Every year there are more posts to vote for, the aggregate of posts made that year plus posts made in previous years.  So ever more votes to cast in a specific year.  You count the votes on that aggregate.  But you don't aggregate posts the same way, you only use the posts made in the specific year.  Actual ratios are 2.98, 1.95, 1.17, 0.97, 0.91, 0.84, 0.60.  The OP's observation is correct.

Comment: @HansPassant: Are you sure you didn't divide votes of the year by posts until end of the year, because that's pessimistic. We probably want to splic votes on post from that year and votes on posts from previous years though.

Comment: @HansPassant: I disagree (a bit). The figures in my post compare two activities: voting versus posting, in a given year. Your figures would be avg votes/post made that year assuming votes are spread equally across all post made to date. That's not the case at all, about 50% votes are for posts made that year in 2013 and 2014. Obviously 100% of votes in 2008 were were for posts in 2008, so there's a down trend. But that agrees with my "analysis" - old posts get more votes because they've been around longer.

Comment: @HansPassant: looked at the data differently, the second illustrates (I think) what you described in your comment.